# Why are my Orchard CMS widgets not populating the Id property when I export them through with Import/Export module?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

When I export my Orchard CMS site, most content items have an Id property that is populated with a unique string.

For example, an Html widget may export like this:

```
<HtmlWidget Id="/Identifier=c1bc3509bc7144f28b5797f24522b7b1" Status="Published">
```

However, all of the widgets that I have created in my modules are being exported similarly to:

```
<MyWidget Id="" Status="Published">
```

Why are my widgets not being exported with an Id? Do I need to do something to set an Id? What am I doing wrong?

Additionally- when I import my recipe, the items that get exported without an Id do not import unless I manually edit each of them in the recipe to have a unique Id. And even then- once I manually add a unique Id, the import tool does not appear to be able to recognise these items and will therefore create the items again; resulting in duplicate widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to add the `IdentityPart` to be attached to my widgets. You can do this in your migrations file by using

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("MyWidget",
            cfg => cfg
                .WithPart("IdentityPart"));
```